# JavaScript conversion to Float32Array and back for WebGL readPixels

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, typed-arrays

I am storing `id` (which is a value comprised in 24bit-range) into an `Float32Array(3)` for latter retrieval in WebGL:

```
var r = 0, 
    g = 0, 
    b = id;
if (b >= 65536) { 
    r = ~~(b / 65536);
    b -= r * 65536; 
}
if (b >= 256) { 
    g = ~~(b / 256); 
    b -= g * 256;
}
var fa = new Float32Array([r/255, g/255, b/255]);
```

For the sake of completeness, here is how i am using that value:

```
gl.uniform3fv(uniforms['u_id'], fa);
```

...and this is how i get my `id` back from `WebGLRenderingContext.readPixels()`:

```
var result = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, result);
var id = result[0] << 16 | result[1] << 8 | result[2];
```

Which is the correct way to split that value into my `Float32Array`? I strongly believe that such task could be accomplished in a more efficient and elegant way (actually, what i am doing is working but is really hurting my eyes).

Comment: What are the definitions of "efficient" and  "elegant" at Question?

Comment: If `b` is greater than `65536` at `if (b >= 65536) {` `b` would also be greater than `256` at next line at `if (b >= 256) { `, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 correct, this is how it is meant. i hadn't time to make it better in the past, i am trying now to restyle that ugly (but working) piece of code

Comment: I don't know that well bitwise operations, so won't be able to help toward the end goal, but no, if b is greater than 65536 in the first if block, it is not said it will be greater than 256 in the second one: you do modify b in this first if block. e.g if `id` is `65536` initially, then when reaching the second block b will be `0`.

Comment: @Kaiido correct, this is not always the case, but i believe the question was if the sequence of the if-blocks matters, and that is true.- i am aware that that stuff is too much convoluted

Comment: What is this supposed to do? If you're just storing the first second and third bytes, that's trivial with bit-manipulation.

Comment: @harold i guess yes, but i wasn't able to get it done right, dunno why, my fault

Comment: Here try this `[(id >> 16) / 255, ((id >> 8) & 255) / 255, (id & 255) / 255]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` has a form like this:

```
0000 0000 rrrr rrrr gggg gggg bbbb bbbb
```

A part (r, g or b) can be extracted by putting it in the lowest byte and masking the rest away. Sometimes one of those steps is unnecessary. So:

```
b = id & 255  // b is already in the low byte, so no shift
g = (id >> 8) & 255
r = id >> 16  // no mask because there is nothing "above" r
```

This can be put together with the division and putting it in an array:

```
[(id >> 16) / 255, ((id >> 8) & 255) / 255, (id & 255) / 255]
```